# How should I rewrite Legacy code in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my code.

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'projects' }
    ])
)(ProjectDetails);
```

The error says.

---

index.js:1 Warning: Legacy context API has been detected within a strict-mode tree.

The old API will be supported in all 16.x releases, but applications using it should migrate to the new version.

Please update the following components: Connect(FirestoreConnect(ProjectDetails)), FirestoreConnect(ProjectDetails), Provider

Learn more about this warning here: https://reactjs.org/link/legacy-context
at Provider

---

I updated react-redux-firebase from 2.4 to 3.10.
But some errors happen.
It seems that I have to change many codes.

---

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Module.
src/index.js:20
17 |
18 | const store = createStore(rootReducer,
19 |   compose(

> 20 |   applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase,getFirestore})),
> 21 |   reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
> 22 |   reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
> 23 |   )

---

Comment: What version of react-redux-firebase are you using? This [issue](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/581) was solved some time ago.

Comment: I am using @2.4.1

Comment: I suggest you [update](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/package.json#L3) it and see if that solves it. You can do the update in a new branch so it's easy to roll back when you get stuck.